# How to run a script on LXDE startup in Wheezy?

Tags: boot, raspbian-wheezy, script, cron

I have two scripts, `slideshow_start.sh` which is the main script I am trying to run (simply a slideshow using feh). And `slideshow_start.py` which just calls `slideshow_start.sh` using `os.system("<path to>slideshow_start")`. Both are executable work fine normally.

I have tried everything I can find to run either one at startup, but nothing works. Here is what I've tried so far:

using cron:

`@reboot python /path/to/file/slideshow_start.py
@reboot sh /path/to/file/slideshow_start.sh
@reboot bash /path/to/file/slideshow_start.sh
@reboot /path/to/file/slideshow_start.sh
@reboot /path/to/file/slideshow_start
@reboot /path/to/file/slideshow_start.py`

edit /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart:

`@/usr/bin/sudo /path/to/file/slideshow_start.py
@/usr/bin/python /path/to/file/slideshow_start.py`

edit /etc/rc.local:

`/path/to/file/slideshow_start
/path/to/file/slideshow_start.sh
/path/to/file/slideshow_start.py`

Please help.

Comment: Running on (re)boot (including via rc.local) isn't the same as running post LXDE's startup, and will not work for GUI applications.  LXDE's startup requires you either log in via the display manager or you log in on a console and `startx`.  If you are looking to run a GUI app at boot with no login, you want to research setting up a *kiosk*.

Comment: @goldilocks - OK that makes sense. Does feh need to be run from LXDE? I don't necessarily need to boot into the desktop if it'll work from the main command line. And if that's the case, will one of the above solutions I've tried work?

Answer (score 1):

I would try using [xinitrc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xinitrc). But I'm not 100% sure if this works.